# Performance Issues when rendering large tables in React

Tags: reactjs, html-table, calendar, event-handling

I am creating a calendar component for scheduling using an HTML table and I want to be able to drag around an event similar to google cal. When I drag the element, I would like the background of the cell i am dragging over to change using the onDragEnter handler. I do this by saving an identifier to the cell in a state and then making the background style on the cell conditional.

However, the background update appears to lag behind the user because the table is very large and since the cells are mapped, it is re-rendering the whole table. See below.

[image]

See the code below.

```
const [dragCellNum, setDragCellNum] = useState(null);


const handleDragIn = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    setDragCellNum(e.target.id);
};

// simplified return
return 
<table>
  <tbody>
    // Rows are mapped as well.
    <tr>
      // Mapping all the cells here
      {data.map(x=> 
         <td
           key={id}
           id={id}
           style={{
             // Here is conditional BG color change
             backgroundColor: id === dragCellNum ? '#CCCCCC' : #FFFFFF,
           }}
           onDragEnter={handleDragIn}
         >
      )}
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I left out a lot for simplicity's sake, but the table is large. Essentially, I am wondering if there is a way to use react memo or ref or a whole different way to do this to keep the entire table from re-rendering.

Thanks, everyone.

Comment: Have you tried using virtual tables?

Comment: @SampurnG I haven't and I'm not familiar with this. Can you enlighten me?

Comment: Just watched some videos on react-virtualized and i think that may work. Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: It's better to use virtual tables, whenever dealing with large data, as they provide faster loading and can easily deal with the data. Here's a link to a [medium article](https://yudhajitadhikary.medium.com/optimize-your-code-by-using-react-virtualized-a9c814031c27) for implementation